# pasting issue to a Rich text editor in Citrix

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard, citrix

if I copy some text from MsWord or Notepad and want to paste it into a rich text editor that is used in my program that is running on my own machine: it is working BUT if I do the same in my program that is running on Citrix, it throws "Cannot read or write to clipboard" error.

I have no idea how to approach this issue.. any suggestions?

Comment: Is this happening only in RichTextEditBoxes or is it happening also in regular textboxes?

Comment: Does your Citrix Session have access to the clipboard and vice versa?

Comment: @Ardman:  yes. I can copy paste in other places.

Comment: Can't reproduce it on my end. Maybe something to do with your Citrix settings?

Comment: yeah, maybe.. it is too specific I think, I myslef voted to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

How much data are you putting on the clipboard?  If it is a lot of data it could be that it's in the process of transferring the data over your ICA connection.

Comment: We have two citrix boxes. it was working on one of them and not on  the other one. so we think it is because one of these is jsut out of sync with the latest version of text editor control.